# How to prove this correctness principle of transposition of lists of lists in Coq?

Tags: coq, list-manipulation

I have defined the function `transpose` as follows:

```
Fixpoint transpose {X : Type} (len : nat) (tapes : list (list X)) : list (list X) :=
  match tapes with
  | [] => repeat [] len
  | t :: ts => zipWith cons t (transpose len ts)
  end.
```

where

```
Definition zipWith {X Y Z} (f : X -> Y -> Z) (xs : list X) (ys : list Y) : list Z :=
  map (fun '(x, y) => f x y) (combine xs ys).
```

Since the `0 x n` matrix is encoded as `[]`, I use the additional parameter `len` to denote the number `n`.

I define the function

```
Definition ij_error {X : Type} (i j : nat) (l : list (list X)) : option X :=
  match nth_error l i with
  | Some l' => nth_error l' j
  | None => None
  end.
```

Note that `nth_error` and `combine` are [Library Functions](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Lists.List.html)

I would like to prove the following lemma, but I am not sure how I should do so. The large number of variables for inducting, and the nested cases is quite overwhelming. Any help is appreciated.

```
Lemma transpose_spec {X : Type} : forall len (tapes : list (list X)),
  (forall t,
    In t tapes -> length t = len)
  -> forall i j,
    ij_error i j tapes = ij_error j i (transpose len tapes).
Proof.
Admitted.
```

Note: I [have proven](https://gist.github.com/Agnishom/d686ef345d7c7b408362e1d2c9c64581) a number of other lemmas about transpose and zipWith which may be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should not be scared.
While doing the induction, we will discover the lemmas you are still missing to finish the proof.

```ml
Lemma transpose_spec {X : Type} : forall len (tapes : list (list X)),
  (forall t,
    In t tapes -> length t = len)
  -> forall i j,
    ij_error i j tapes = ij_error j i (transpose len tapes).
Proof.
induction tapes as [|l tapes IHt]; simpl; intros H.
- intros i j; rewrite ij_error_nil.
  (* missing lemmas about ij_error and repeat *)
  admit.
- induction i as [|i IHi].
  + intros j.
    (* missing lemmas about ij_error 0 j and ij_error i 0 *)
    admit.
  + (* missing lemmas about ij_error (S i) j and ij_error j (S i *)
    admit.
Qed.
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, that proof scheme worked out. I have updated the [gist](https://gist.github.com/Agnishom/d686ef345d7c7b408362e1d2c9c64581) in case someone is curious

Comment: Did you manage to do it with  a single induction on `tapes`? (maybe `Hi` is not used so a simple `destruct i` is enough)

Comment: You are right. `destruct i` was enough.

Comment: [ssreflect version](https://gist.github.com/davidjao/1a857a3c2d39dfec5cde0339d742be10) for OP or anyone else who would like it.